# DRBL: Clonezilla won't start (the PXE boot menu command only makes some flicker)

Tags: pxe-boot, clonezilla, drbl

I have a Ubuntu 11.04 (amd64) PC with DRBL server on it. I set it to provide Clonezilla in partition restore mode. Client PCs do boot in PXE and DRBL menu is shown but the Clonezilla menu item won't work at all - nothing happens except a little screen flickering. At the same time, netinstall mode appears to work just fine, as well as memtest and local boot options.

Here is a screenshot of a client VM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/naEkj.png

Same goes for physical PCs. Neither automatic nor manual Clonezilla boot proceed. What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: At the menu where you took the screenshot, press tab and verify that all the paths are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check your TFTP server logs.  Don't have them? Edit /etc/xinetd.d/tftp and add -v to the command line.

Going right back to the menu like that is a pretty good sign it's unable to retrieve one of the files.  Maybe you have a typo or the files aren't where they should be.